# Exclude symbolic links from rsync without excessive notification

Tags: rsync

I want to exclude symbolic links from an `rsync`, but `--no-links` floods my terminal with `skipping non-regular file` for every link, taking focus from other important information from `rsync`.

How can I exclude links without being pestered about each individual occurrence? The following are not acceptable solutions:

1. Using the `-q` option, as this suppresses *all* output from `rsync`
2. Filtering the message with `grep`
3. Meticulously altering my include file around the links are not good options.

If this is is impossible (as it may seem): Why is skipping non-regular files considered so important that the user is explicitly warned about every single one of them even when he has specified he wants to exclude them? I'm tempted to take this up as an issue with the developer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rsync "skipping non-regular file" message when not copying links](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324721/rsync-skipping-non-regular-file-message-when-not-copying-links)

Comment: @Marco: It's a duplicate, but I'm not happy with the proposed answer. Read updated post.

Comment: Why is it not an option to filter those unwanted messages away?

Comment: @ilkkachu: Just seems very hacky...

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to see messages about *any* skipped files, you can use `--info=skip0` if your version of `rsync` is not too old.

If you don't want to see messages on skipped symbolic links, but *do* want the messages if any other files are skipped, then unfortunately `rsync`'s output control options don't seem to be fine-grained enough for that.

See `rsync --info=help` for a list of things you can adjust in `rsync` output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `--files-from` to define the list of files to sync, and use `find` to exclude symlinks:

```
rsync --files-from=<(find . ! -type l -print) . TARGET/
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but then I have to run a separate `rsync` for these files only. It would have been nice to include it with the main `rsync` backup.

Comment: @forthin nothing stops you from running the find from the top level of your backup source. And use elaborate rules to only skip symlinks in directories you want to ignore them :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this after your `rsync` command:

```
| grep -v "skipping non-regular file"
```

if those are the only things generating those messages, it will filter them. You may even do a `"^skipping"` if it's at the beginning of the line.

Comment: That's what I do, but the original poster specified that 'grep' was not acceptable.